# Web-page with the same URL, but different parameters still counted the same to a previous?

Tags: php, html, url, web, indexing

For **static** sites we can have a "page.html". This page do not have any parameters such as "?param=value.

And it will be indexed by search engines and other things. No problems here.

But I would like to know what actually happens with indexation when a single page, for instance "lessons.php?lessonID=1" has some parameters and its content is really different in contrast with page "lessons.php?lessonID=2".

Are they indexed as two different pages?
Are they at least condsidered being two different pages from a "machine" view?

(P.S: I am asking because I am going to install disqus comments sistem on such a page and I don't know will the comments be different deneping on different page parameters such as lessonID).

Comment: I'd imagine the parameters are seen as different content on the same page/url. why not use htaccess to pretty those url's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "Search Engine Optimisation", also known as "SEO".

This is a very broad field, with a whole lot of factors that can influence how well a page is ranked in the search engines. But you're right in thinking that the query parameters can make a difference.

Query parameters are considered part of a static URL, and will therefore be indexed by Google and others. If you have a URL with query parameters, then it is possible for it to appear in a Google search.

Ten years ago, you might have written most of your site like this, with query parameters on virtually every URL, and Google would happily have ranked them high up in its listings.

However, current SEO best practice to avoid query parameters for URLs that you want to be indexed. Search engines strongly favour URLS without them, so although your pages will still be indexed, they are likely to appear a long way down the rankings.

To boost your rankings, there are many techniques, but the first one you should try is converting your site so that it doesn't use URLs with query parameters.

If you look at this site (ie StackOverflow), you'll see that the URLs for questions looks like this `/questions/31873163/question-description`.

The `question-description` part is purely there for SEO -- it gives Google a bunch of relevant keywords in the URL, but it is completely ignored when the page is loaded.

The important bit is `/questions/31873163/`. When the page loads, this is processed as a query paramter something like `questionID=31873163`.

All modern development frameworks support generating this kind of URL instead of query parameters, specifically in order to improve the SEO ranking.

If you're not using a modern development framework, you can still do it manually by configuring your web server. For example, if you're using an Apache web server, you will need to use its `mod_rewrite` feature to pre-process incoming URLs with slashes so that your PHP code receives them as query parameters. There's loads of tutorials on the web to help you do this, though it can be tricky to do manually so I'd recommend using a framework like Laravel so that you don't need to get your hands too dirty with mod_rewrite code.

Answer (score 0):

try rewrite you lessons.php using rewrite_mod

- lessons.php?lessonID=1 > /lessons/lesson1.html
- lessons.php?lessonID=2 > /lessons/lesson2.html
- lessons.php?lessonID=3 > /lessons/lesson3.html

etc.

```
RewriteRule ^lessons\.php?lessonID=([0-9]+)$ lessons/lesson$1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the person indexing a URL to decide which parts of it are important.

In theory, every URL parameter is significant and the URL which is indexed includes the query string. However, Google knows that often URL parameters can appear in any order and some of them don't primarily affect the content (like any of the analytics `utm_*` parameters), so will ignore them while indexing.

Check out what they have to say about "active" and "passive" parameters at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en